# Required Precision in Calculating Reciprocals of $n$ and $\frac{1}{n}$ to Recover the Integer

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation, computer-arithmetic

Suppose I am given a large integer $n$ and a small positive value $\epsilon$ such that I am to compute $\frac{1}{n}$, and then compute the reciprocal of that, in order to recover $n$ to within an accuracy of $\epsilon$.

My question is: What precision would be required in the initial computation of $\frac{1}{n}$, and then in the subsequent calculation of its reciprocal, in order recover $n$ to within \epsilon?

Comment: If you compute to a precision of $\delta$ then we have that $1/(1/n)$ would roughly be $n^*\approx \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}+\delta}+\delta$. If you have $n-1/2 < n^* < n + 1/2$ then you can get back $n$ by rounding. Solve this for $\delta$.

Comment: @Winther : Usually the precision is relative, so that you get $n^*=n\frac{1+δ_2}{1+δ_1}$ which with $|δ_k|<\mu$ gives $-1/2<2n\mu<1/2$ as condition, that is, $n<2^{51}$.